# How to get the Asp.Net Core routing engine to strictly respect the route specified?

Tags: url, routes, asp.net-core, seo

**Background**
For SEO purposes it's important that there not be two urls for the same page, otherwise Google will see one of the pages as having "duplicate content" and this will result in google reducing the page's ranking in the search engine results.

**Issue**
In Asp.Net Core, when using attribute based routine like so:

```
 public class ExampleController: Controller {

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/example/")]
    public IActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }     

}
```

This route returns the index.cshtml page in response to url requests for both `/example/` **AND** `/example`.  However, I only want this to respond to the route that I explicitly specified, i.e. `/example/`.   If a request comes in for `/example` I don't want this action method to respond, the system should 404 instead.

**Question**
What do I need to do at a global level to force the routing engine to strictly respect the route specified?

Comment: Why do you want this? this is a general rule every webserver uses, is that the trailing slash doesn't matter for routing. also normally the path of www.example.com is generaly `/` so its normalized to a trailing slash often.

Comment: You could add a middleware that always forwards to url with trailing slash if trailing slash is missing if you'd really want this, but this might be to a general solution for you?

Comment: I could add middleware, but it's messy since most urls shouldn't end in a trailing slash given that most will be specifying a view rather than a directory of views.  What I really want is for Asp.Net Core to honor what I specified in the attribute based route and I'd be willing to rewrite that part of the routing engine to get it if necessary.

Comment: I just discovered that this issue has been reported on GitHub and I added info there to.  For those interested: https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/issues/380

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea why someone downvoted this questions, I can only guess they don't understand the seriousness of the issue. Perhaps they don't understand the importance of Search Engine Optimization. Researching this issue with the Asp.Net Core framework took many hours so I'm sharing that work here to help others.

It turns out that this issue has been [reported](https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/issues/380) in the GitHub repo and is under consideration for a future fix.  Apparently the primary reason that Asp.Net Core exhibits this buggy behavior is that the prior version of MVC did. Go figure.

Currently there is no way to force the Asp.Net Core Routing engine to strictly match the declared routes.  In fact, when an attribute based route like `/example/` is declared it's store internally in the routing data structures as `/example` which shows just how deep this issue runs.  It's highly unfortunate that the data is stored this way, making it impossible for the routing engine to discern the difference between `/example` and `/example/` when strictly speaking they are two **different** endpoints.

**Working around the Issue**
Since I can't wait for a fix, I had to implement a work around. The way I solve this was to implement middleware that runs early in the pipeline that checks all incoming requests to ensure that a url only ends in a slash if it specifies a path to a directory, this middleware also requires that any path that ends at a directory must end in a slash. It uses a 301 redirect to the proper url if a request comes in for a url that does not follow these rules.

So for example, in given the following:

> /somefile.cshtml
>  /somedir/anotherdir/file.cshtml
>   /somedir/anotherdir/index.cshtml

A request for `/somefile/` gets redircted to `/somefile` and a request for `/somedir/anotherdir/file/` gets redirected to `/somedir/anotherdir/file` and a request for `/somedir/anotherdir` gets redircted to `/somedir/anotherdir/`

This approach resolves the [duplicate content issue](https://moz.com/learn/seo/duplicate-content) that is inherent in the default routing engine treating `/somedir` and `/somedir/` as the same route. The approach does this by ensuring that only one of these ever makes it to the routing engine.

I should add, that while this work around "fixes" the issue in a sense, it's not nearly as efficient as having a routing engine that can be told to strictly respect the routes specified. Hopefully we will have such an option for the routing in the 2.0 release.

Comment: If it were somewhat easy to provide the code I would.  Unfortunately the code that handles this is embedded in a much larger body of work that is a CanonicalUrlMiddlware module, and so the aspect of whether the url should end in a slash or not is just one minor detail of that middleware.  I'd be happy to answer questions about the approach though if you have specific questions.

Comment: @RonC How to identify the folder or file case, like you did?

Comment: @Fantasterei in my case all url paths are lowercase so that’s how I avoided that issue.

Comment: Same for me. But how to find out if it's a file or a directory. I used an IO function, checking for .cshtml file (without index) to identify. Is there any better way?

Comment: @Fantasterei  What I do is maintain a .txt file of all directory paths, one per line in the file.  Then when a request comes in for say /have/fun  I check in the text file to see if /have/fun/ exists, if so, I 301 redirect to that.  if not, I let the request for /have/fun proceed.  Likewise if a request for /not/fun/ come in I check the .txt file of directories to see if it's a valid directory or not, if not, I do a 301 redirect to /not/fun  (For clarity I don't actually search the .txt file directly, I actually load all those directory paths into a list that I can search as needed.)